# Theano casting int up to int64 - how to avoid this?

Tags: theano

I'm getting a lot of headache learning Theano. Right now I have the issue hat I'm passing an integer `n_samples` that is larger than `32767` to that function. This causes the compiler to cast it up to a `int64` which does not work:

```
    ([Wn,bhn, bvn], updates) = theano.scan(fn=self.cd_step,

                                    outputs_info=[self.W, self.bias_hidden, self.bias_visible],
                                    non_sequences=[learning_rate,                                                         
                                                   self.D, n_samples, n_hidden],
                                    n_steps=10,
                                    strict=True)
```

I tried to pass it with `nump.float32(n_samples)` but this is not working either.

How can I fix this issue and cast it to `float32` so the compiler shuts up?

Answer (score 0):

If your input is larger than 32-bit integer you should pass it to 64-bit integer variable, there's two way that I know how to cast a variable in theano:

first:

```
y = T.iscalar('y')
z = T.cast(y,'int64') * 10000000
f = theano.function([y],z)

print f(100000000)
```

y is a 32-bit variable, so instead of directly multiply y with 10^7 we cast it to 'int64' first.

second:

```
y = T.lscalar('y')
z = y * 10000000
f = theano.function([y],z)

print f(100000000)
```

instead of using "iscalar" try to use "lscalar" which refers to 'int64' variable

hope it helps